# C# find all class implement interface without generic type

Tags: c#, reflection, typeof

I have `Interface` with `Generic Type`

```
public interface IWork<T>
{
    void Work(MySession session, T json);
}
```

I am trying to find all `Classes` that implement the `Interface` with all generic types, when trying this code

```
var type = typeof(IWork<>);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Its return the `Interface` it self.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that no class/ interface will extend the generic interface directly, they will all extend an instantiation of the generic interface for a given type parameter ( be it a concrete type such as `string` or another type parameter). You need to check if any of the interfaces a class implements are instances of the generic interface:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        var type = typeof(IWork<>);
        var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                    .Where(p => p.GetInterfaces().Any(i=> i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == type))
                    .ToArray();

        // types will contain GenericClass, Cls2,Cls,DerivedInterface  defined below
    }
}

public interface IWork<T>
{
    void Work(object session, T json);
}

class GenericClass<T> : IWork<T>
{
    public void Work(object session, T json)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class Cls2 : IWork<string>
{
    public void Work(object session, string json)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class Cls : GenericClass<string> { }

interface DerivedInterface : IWork<string> { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the Where the !p.IsInterface or the p.IsClass to remote the interface from the results.

```
var type = typeof(IWork<>);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface);
```